# How to pass arguments to *args after keyword arguments

Tags: python

i have defined a function that takes positional as well as *args and **kwargs arguments.

```
def fun(a,b,*aa,**bb):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(aa)
    print(bb)
fun(1,2,3,4,dd=4,pp=5)
fun(b=1,a=2,aa=(4,5,6),dd=4,pp=5)
```

It works with the first call . But when i give keyword arguments to a and b how can i pass any value to *aa

Comment: You can't. The first positional argument will become `a` and if you give it as keyword, it will be set twice and raise an exception. To fill `aa` you need more than two positional arguments and no keyword arguments `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3):

You **CAN NOT**

Positional arguments are based on *position* which is clear by its name as well.

So, you can not pass the positional arguments after passing the keyword arguments, in other words, you need to pass positional arguments first before passing the keyword arguments.

The explanation and code snippet from [docs for keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

> When a final formal parameter of the form **name is present, it
> receives a dictionary (see Mapping Types — dict) containing all
> keyword arguments except for those corresponding to a formal
> parameter. This may be combined with a formal parameter of the form
> *name (described in the next subsection) which receives a tuple containing the positional arguments beyond the formal parameter list.
> **(*name must occur before **name.)** For example, if we define a function
> like this:

```py
def cheeseshop(kind, *arguments, **keywords):
    print("-- Do you have any", kind, "?")
    print("-- I'm sorry, we're all out of", kind)
    for arg in arguments:
        print(arg)
    print("-" * 40)
    for kw in keywords:
        print(kw, ":", keywords[kw])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined your function as

```
def fun(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
```

it means that you expect always two standard positional arguments and any number of additional positional and keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what was asked, BUT if the goal is to pass some named arguments and a variable-length (maybe empty) set of optional arguments in a function call, then a possible workaround is to pack the optional arguments into a tuple and pass it via a named argument `aa`, whose default value is empty tuple:

```py
def foo(a,b,aa=()):
    print("a=",a)
    print("b=",b,*aa)

foo(1,2)
foo(1,2, ("c=", 3) )
foo(b=1, a=2)
foo(b=1, a=2, aa=("c=", 3))
```

output:

```
a= 1
b= 2
a= 1
b= 2 c= 3
a= 2
b= 1
a= 2
b= 1 c= 3
```